# MultiversX Dapp tutorial - Sender not allowed

Tags: multiversx

I was following this tutorial: https://docs.elrond.com/developers/tutorials/your-first-dapp/

With the help of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdkgvlK3rb8

But I think there is some difference between the dApp repository and the tutorial, first the `src/config.devnet.tsx` disappeared we now have an `src/config.tsx` already present (not a big deal).

I'm blocked when I try to do the ping, in the console I got the error `Sender not allowed` with value `erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq6gq4hu`.

So my guess is that I've done something wrong deploying the contract, but I tried to redeploy other contracts I always ended up with the same error.

I tried natively on my ubuntu 20.04, and then in a devcontainer using an Ubuntu 22.04 image.

I'm pretty new to MultiversX, Crypto (and also Node) so I might be missing something.

Comment: Can you provide some more context or a tx hash to understand what exactly have you been trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I've just completed the tutorial and I think that you put the wrong SC address in `src/config.tsx`. The address you provided is the SC that handles other SC deployments. You have to replace it with your SC's address generated after deployment.